# Crossfilter query

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

Is it possible to filter a crossfilter dataset which has an array as the value?

For example, say I have the following dataset:

```
var data = [
  {
    bookname: "the joy of clojure",
    authors: ["Michael Fogus", "Chris Houser"],
    tags: ["clojure", "lisp"]
  },
  {
    bookname: "Eloquent Ruby",
    authors: ["Russ Olsen"],
    tags: ["ruby"]
  },
  {
    bookname: "Design Patterns in Ruby",
    authors: ["Russ Olsen"],
    tags: ["design patterns", "ruby"]
  }
];
```

Is there an easy way to access the books which are tagged by an particular tag? And also the books which have a particular author? The way I understand how to use crossfilter so far has me doing something like this:

```
var filtered_data = crossfilter(data);
var tags = filtered_data.dimension(function(d) {return d.tags});
var tag = tags.group();
```

And then when I access the grouping (like so):

```
tag.all()
```

I get this:

```
[{key: ["clojure", "lisp"], value: 1}, 
 {key: ["design patterns", "ruby"], value: 1}, 
 {key: ["ruby"], value: 1}]
```

When I would rather have this:

```
[{key: "ruby", value: 2}, 
 {key: "clojure", value: 1}, 
 {key: "lisp", value: 1},
 {key: "design patterns", value: 1}]
```

Comment: I believe my questions are getting more and more obscure with time. This is rather unfortunate.

Comment: Not obscure at all. I was looking for exactly this today.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've added comments to the code below. Big picture: use reduce function.

```
var data = ...
var filtered_data = crossfilter(data);
var tags = filtered_data.dimension(function(d) {return d.tags});

tags.groupAll().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial).value()
```

Notice how I've used **groupAll()** instead of **group()** b/c we want our reduce functions (defined below) to operate on one group rather than 3 groups.

Now the reduce functions should look like this:

```
/*
 v is the row in the dataset

 p is {} for the first execution (passed from reduceInitial). 
 For every subsequent execution it is the value returned from reduceAdd of the prev row
*/
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  v.tags.forEach (function(val, idx) {
     p[val] = (p[val] || 0) + 1; //increment counts
  });
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
   //omitted. not useful for demonstration
}

function reduceInitial() {
  /* this is how our reduce function is seeded. similar to how inject or fold 
   works in functional languages. this map will contain the final counts 
   by the time we are done reducing our entire data set.*/
  return {};  
}
```

Comment: Ah.. I completely overlooked using the groupAll function. Thank you, I haven't tested out your answer but it definitely looks like it has the right combination of ideas that I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Could the answer's author or else someone complete this answer? As the question was "Is there an easy way to access the books which are tagged by an particular tag? And also the books which have a particular author?" but presently this answer only goes as far generating some ".value()" result and its not clear (at least to me, perhaps from being brand new to Crossfilter, but still) how to produce these final answers the question asked for, and which I could use knowing, too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was useful for finding the selection average without respect to individual groups. Thank you.

Comment: @DestinyArchitect: Untested, but I think you're looking for something like this: `var reduction = tags.groupAll().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);` `var books_on_design_patterns = reduction.value()["design patterns"]`

Comment: This would also require `reduceAdd` to store the full set of values in `p[val]`; ie. `p["design patterns"]` would have to contain each book on design patterns via a variation of the `reduceAdd` code above (the current version only stores the count).

Answer (score 2):

I've never used "crossfilter" (I'm assuming this is a JS library). Here are some pure JS methods though.

This...

```
data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.authors.indexOf("Michael Fogus") !== -1;
})
```

returns this:

```
[{bookname:"the joy of clojure", authors:["Michael Fogus", "Chris Houser"], tags:["clojure", "lisp"]}]
```

This...

```
var res = {};
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.tags.forEach(function(tag) {
    res.hasOwnProperty(tag) ? res[tag]++ : res[tag] = 1
  });
})
```

returns this:

```
({clojure:1, lisp:1, ruby:2, 'design patterns':1})
```

To either of these, you can apply `d3.entries` to get your `{key:"ruby", value: 2}` format.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but the reason I'm using crossfilter is to sort through some fairly large datasets. [Crossfilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) is actually another mike bostock library and is a pretty interesting idea, if i could figure out how to use it properly..