# Crossfilter filtering and displaying on array properties

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have an array of data objects like this:

```
{
  index: "M1",
  first: "First",
  last: "Last",
  distance: 5,
  specialties: ["Pediatrics", "Internal"],
  languages: ["English", "French"]
}
```

In addition to filtering by distance:

```
var cf = crossfilter(physicians);
var byDistance = cf.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.distance;
});
```

I'd like to filter by specialty. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044935/crossfilter-query), but that just gives me a structure with a count of each specialty for the entire dataset.

Ideally I'd like to display matching specialties based on the distance filter, and use specialties to further filter the results.

Is that possible given the structure of my objects? Is there some easier way to represent the data that would lend itself better to filtering?

Thanks. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/colin_young/xRQjX/35/

Answer (score 3):

[Support for custom filter functions](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/pull/64) has been added in crossfilter-1.2.0. You should now be able to do:

```
var specialties = cf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.specialties;
});

specialties.filterFunction(function(d) {
    return d.indexOf("specialty") >= 0;
});
```

Alternatively, you can make a dimension for each possible specialty:

```
var pediatrics = cf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.specialties.indexOf("pediatrics") >= 0;
});

var internal = cf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.specialties.indexOf("internal") >= 0;
});
```

and run filters on those (but this only supports AND conditions).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've been too busy to get to trying this, but I will do my best over the weekend to test it out.