# d3.csv map data as an array

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, dc.js

I'm currently working with dc.js, crossfilter.js, and d3.js to render some visualizations. I've come across a post pretty similar to what I was looking for here [Crossfilter query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044935/crossfilter-query/12191729#12191729) and here [d3 csv data loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986435/d3-csv-data-loading).

What i'm aiming to do is to parse my csv, and for a certain column, parse it as an array within each object row. for instance, i have:

my data currently comes out as:

> [ 
> {FY: 2011, proj_name: "project 1", category: "fruit", subcategory: "strawberry, mango", total: 1510},
>   {FY: 2011, proj_name: "project 2", category: "fruit", subcategory: "orange, mango", total: 100},
>   {FY: 2011, proj_name: "project 2", category: "vegetable", subcategory: "celery", total: 100}
>  ]

but i'm looking to format the data as so:

> [ 
> {FY: 2011, proj_name: "project 1", category: "fruit", subcategory: ["strawberry", "mango"], total: 1510},
>   {FY: 2011, proj_name: "project 1", category: "fruit", subcategory: ["orange", "mango"], total: 100},
>   
> {FY: 2011, proj_name: "project 1", category: "vegetable", subcategory: ["celery"], total: 100}
> ]

Is this something I can just put in data.forEach(function (d)) ?

```
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) { 
    data.forEach(function (d) { 
        d.FY = +d.FY; 
        d.total = +d.total; 
        d.subcategory = d.subcategory.split(/,/); 
        }) 
    })
```

I don't think is correct and it simply isn't working, but what I'm getting at here is that it's something that needs to be done repetitively within this column specifically so that I can bucket the subcategories as tags later on.. Any thoughts/feedback?

Much thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 already has this covered, the format for d3.csv is: `d3.csv(url[, accessor][, callback])` where accessor is a function called for each row in the csv to transform the data.  Try this:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) { 
  return {
    FY: +d.FY,
    total: +d.total,
    category: d.category,
    subcategory: d.subcategory.split(/,/)
  };
});
```